# cox model in python - covariates with multiple levels?

Tags: python, cox-regression

I'm using coxphfitter. The model builds; however, I have covariates with multiple levels, e.g. 0, 1, 2, and the model does not account for these. I've double checked my work in SPSS, and see that it does not.

How can I get the model to give me p-values for covariate "smoking_status"?
smoking_status (0) - this is my reference value
smoking_status (1)
smoking_status (2)`

I see that in older versions of lifelines, you could use

```
    "formula=Surv(time, event) ~ C(smoking_status, Treatment(0)"
```

to get this, but it doesn't work anymore. (https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fitters/regression/CoxPHFitter.html)

```
# Cox regression
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter
from lifelines.utils import concordance_index as cindex
cohort = cohort[['event', 'time', 'smoking_status']]

# create a Cox proportional hazards model with two covariates and fit it to the data
cph = CoxPHFitter()
#cph.fit(cohort, duration_col='time', event_col='event')
cph.fit(cohort, duration_col='time', event_col='event') 
summary_df = cph.summary 
summary_df.style.format({'p': '{:.5f}'})
```